# Dropdown Choice with setNullValid problem

Tags: java, wicket

I m trying to create a `DropDownChoice` with `setNullValid(true)`, I give the model a `Class A` that have a `Class B` on it, and i give it a list of Class B to select, if the Class A already has the Class B the selected Class B doesn't appear as selected on render.

If A.b was not null I would like to already be selected but also one of the options be null.

Thank you for your time

```
    DropDownChoice<B> bChoices = new DropDownChoice<>(DROPDOWN, new PropertyModel<>(a, "b"),
            listOfBs, new ChoiceRenderer<>("name"));
    b.setNullValid(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wicket uses the `IChoiceRenderer#getIdValue()` to find the selected option. If you do not provide custom `IChoiceRenderer` then Wicket will use `ChoiceRenderer` and as an `id` it will use the index of the item in the `List` of options.

See the usages of `#equals()` at https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/7bef3d67c8ccc269f02e8943bf9a22c3cd5438e9/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSingleSelectChoice.java. Even better fire the debugger and see what happens!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that. I implemented the equals and had the same problem.

Comment: What is the debugger saying?

Comment: Hello I resolved it by implementing a IChoiceRenderer and since the class B was a entity i used it's id for the method getIdValue, and with that it works properly, thank for your time.